# Переместить значение тега в атрибут используя xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Привет. Имеется:

```xml
<high>
    <width>
        <field>1</field>
    </width>
    <width>
        <field>1</field>
    </width>
</high>
```

Нужно сделать:

```xml
<high>
      <width field="1"> </width>
      <width field="1"> </width>
</high>
```

И все это при помощи xsl.  Количество width может быть разным, значение field тоже.

Comment: Вопрос решён? Дайте какой-то отклик.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field">
        <xsl:attribute name="field">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Можно добавить ещё один шаблон, чтобы результат в точности до символа соответствовал:

```
    <xsl:template match="width">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```